# Connecting an IoT device to Ubuntu using bluetooth beacon

Tags: ubuntu, bluetooth, embedded, bluetooth-lowenergy, iot

I have a IOT device that I want to connect to Ubuntu through a bluetooth connection. It has some sort of password on its bluetooth beacon. From my understanding my IoT device will share it's settings and all functions that's already "ready to go" thanks to an app/software on Ubuntu if I connect to it using bluetooth. What app/software do I need that will show me all these functions? What do I need to have this illuminate itself?

Answer (score 1):

The command line tool `bluetoothctl` will be the basic tool that you will have on Ubuntu that is a generic Bluetooth Low Energy scanning and exploration tool

If you have Chrome installed, then use the URL: `chrome://bluetooth-internals/#devices` to scan and explore BLE devices.

Often it is easier to use something like [nRF Connect](https://www.nordicsemi.com/Software-and-tools/Development-Tools/nRF-Connect-for-mobile) on a mobile device to better understand the services and data on the IOT device before starting on Linux.

As this is a coding webiste, the API's for Bluetooth on Linux are documented at: https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/doc

And there are examples at:
https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/test